# How do you avoid getting radiation in starbound?

Tags: starbound

I have recently started the Dreadwing mission in Starbound and have come to realize  that I need better weapons so I have landed on a planet with a radiation symbol. I am a newer player so I do not know how to avoid the affects of radiation. Is there a way to avoid the radiation?

Answer (score 3):

You need a [Radiation EPP Upgrade](http://Radiation%20EPP%20Upgrade):

[image]

Its an EPP aka [Environmental Protection Pack](http://starbounder.org/Protection_Pack), you can wear these in your backpack slot to defend you from a variety of hostile environments like radiation, extreme cold, or that fact that there is no breathable air on around you.

To craft this EPP you gonna first need a [Breathing EPP](http://starbounder.org/Breathing_EPP) which can be crafted at the [Anvil](http://starbounder.org/Anvil) using:

- 10 [Glass](http://starbounder.org/Glass)
- 6  [Tungsten Bar](http://starbounder.org/Tungsten_Bar)
- 1  [Living Root](http://starbounder.org/Living_Root)

After you created your Breathing Upgrade Pack, you can upgrade it at a [Forge](http://starbounder.org/Forge) to a Radiation EPP using:

- Your Breathing EPP
- 4 [Copper Bar](http://starbounder.org/Copper_Bar)
- 6 [Titanium Bar](http://starbounder.org/Titanium_Bar)
- 1 [Venom Sample](http://starbounder.org/Venom_Sample)

Answer (score 2):

(This answer applies to the question when it was asked, and was only applicable to the beta version of the game. Paul's answer is correct for the newest version of starbound.)

As you complete missions in the main quest line you gain access to new nanoskin suits. The radiation skin is given when you complete a quest to gather 300 kelp for a fish person on the outpost. Unfortunately this quest does not appear until after you defeat dreadwing. I was able to defeat dreadwing the first time by using some bone swords that I found in a bone biome in combination with the boneboo fruit, which boosts your melee damage.

Comment: This information seems to be outdated.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS OUTDATED**
You need the "Radiation Protector" You obtain it after completing the quest "The Grass is Greener"

Comment: This information seems to be outdated.

Comment: @Paul should i just take it down then

Comment: Take down or note that this was only the case in an older version of starbound. Looks like the questioner abandoned his account so no answer will be chosen as correct, all we can do is help to point people to the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you very nearly made me bang my head.

Secondly, you are given an oxygen suit right before the first mission. Your very next task after your first boss is to head to an ocean planet and collect 300 units of Kelp. This nets you a radiation suit.

Comment: This information seems to be outdated.